# one to many relation ObjectId not working in mongoose mongodb in express typescript

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, express, mongoose

## Mongoose ObjectId is not working for foreign key ref

I have the following code in which I want to convert string to object id so that I can search it is the db.

```js
  public getCstateByCountry = async (country_id: string): Promise<any> => {
    const data = await Cstate.find({ country: Mongoose.Types.ObjectId(country_id) });
    return data;
  };
```

The problem might be typescript strict typing problem. But I don't know why I keep getting this nasty error.

```
Type 'ObjectId' is not assignable to type 'Condition<ObjectId>'.
      Type 'ObjectId' has no properties in common with type 'QuerySelector<ObjectId>'.
```

Also, it does not return the right type of data as type ICstate.
A quick answer will be appreciated as I have very less time.

#### This is the model

```js
const cstateSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
    },
    country: {
      type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Country'
    }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);
```

#### This is the model interface

```js
export interface ICstate extends Document{
    _id: string | number;
    name: string;
    country: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was using Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId in ICstate interface.

Here, Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId is for use in schema. To work with documents, we should use Mongoose.Types.ObjectId.
I changed country in interface from Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId to Mongoose.Types.ObjectId and everything is working now.

Solution Interface:

```js
export interface ICstate extends Document{
    _id: string | number;
    name: string;
    country: Mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
}
```